# Redirect all urls excluding part of url 301

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, http-redirect

I will be changing the url structure on the website

For ex. homepage is now:

```
http://example.com/web/www/
```

and all other url addresses follow this structure:

```
http://example.com/web/www/sample-post/
```

The new address will be (part /web/www/ will be removed):

```
http://example.com
```

and the rest:

```
http://example.com/sample-post/
```

So can I automatically redirect all addresses with one rule that will delete part **/web/www/** from the address or do I have to redirect each address manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the `/web/www` prefix from the requested URL you can do it like this using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteRule On

RewriteRule ^web/www/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `(.*)` part captures the remaining URL-path after `/web/www/`, which is saved in the `$1` backreference, to which we redirect to.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.